# What have i done wrong here? or is there a better alternitive to $answer?

Tags: linux, bash

Lately ive been busy playing around with bash on my linux operating system, and im also using it too sort files. But this does not seem to work. Is there an alternitive way of what im doing or is it wrong?

```
echo -n "Are you sure you would like to delete this/these files? [y/n]"

if [ $answer == "y" ]; then
 echo -n "Which File would you like to delete?"
 rm $answer
else
 echo "canceled!"
fi
```

Comment: The key thing you're missing is `read answer`, because `echo` is just printing stuff out, not reading in the text that you expect.  Secondly, you really shouldn't re-use variables like this; I'd name your first `answer` as `confirm` instead, and the second one as something like `file_to_delete`.  https://linuxhint.com/bash_read_command/

Comment: Oh, So i bassicly just did not have the correct vars in place. I swapped it to what you said and it worked, no problem found!
Thank you

Comment: A word of advice, sanitize user input very-very carefully since it involves `rm`  ...

Comment: For example, there is a big difference between `rm $answer` and `rm "$answer"`

Comment: @YetNT: First, you use a variable  `answer`, which you don't set. Second, you use the variable unquoted, which means that you will get a syntax error, if the content of the variable contains a space.

Comment: `[ "$answer" = y ]`, btw, is a generally less-buggy / more-robust way to do the test. Which does still mean you need to add a `read`. There is no `==` operator standardized for `[` -- the only strong comparison operator that the POSIX standard requires is `=`. And you need to quote all your expansions to prevent other undesired behavior.

Comment: For example, with the original `[ $answer == y ]`, someone could answer `1 = 1 -o n` and the result would be `[ 1 = 1 -o n == y ]`, and any shell that lets `==` be used would call it a success, even though the answer _was not actually_ equal to `y`. Or an empty answer would become just `[ == y ]`, which is a syntax error -- it would still report false but it would report an ugly error at the user. Whereas `[ "$answer" = y ]` will _always_ reliably do what you want.

Comment: if `$answer==y` => `rm $answer` => `rm y`; I'm assuming your script is a) displaying a file (or list of files) to user and b) you want to `rm` said file(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following usage of "read" command

```
read -n1 -p "Are you sure you would like to delete this/these files? [y/n]: " answer

if [ "$answer" == "y" ]; then
 read -p "Which File would you like to delete: " filename
 rm $filename
else
 echo "cancelled!"
fi
```